# Ошибка evaluated but not used при сокращении массива

Tags: golang

Вот пример кода, собственно цель удалить из массива лишние данные,

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "192.168.0.0:123"
    ss := s[strings.Index(s, ":"):]
    fmt.Println(ss)
    s == strings.TrimSuffix(s, ss)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

если пытаться записать результат в исходную переменную то получаем ошибку
 ***evaluated but not used*** , понимаю что можно просто сделать срез в отдельной переменной, но хотелось бы понять можно ли перезаписать уже имеющуюся.

Comment: А зачем вам новая переменная? Можно же сразу в существующую перезаписать: `s = s[:strings.Index(s, ":")]`

Comment: Я так и сделал, просто в таком виде код более читаем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас нет массивов, есть только небольшая опечатка на предпоследней строке.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "192.168.0.0:123"
    ss := s[strings.Index(s, ":"):]
    fmt.Println(ss)
    s = strings.TrimSuffix(s, ss) // оператор сравнения заменён на оператор присваивания
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: Точно, что-то я тупанул с этим оператором.

Comment: ps: строка она же по сути массив, поэтому я её так и обозвал